# Where is a good place to log if some property of domain class changes?

Tags: grails, logging, data-warehouse

```
Class Foo {
  Status status
  String name
}
```

We have some domain class and want to track changes of its properties. My first idea was to add this inside of

```
afterUpdate {}
```

But I am asking me if this the grails way of doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

there is an [audit logging](http://www.grails.org/plugin/audit-logging) plugin that will track changes for you.

If you want to roll your own, yes, you can use the hibernate events to do it.  Documentation [here](http://www.grails.org/doc/latest/guide/5.%20Object%20Relational%20Mapping%20%28GORM%29.html#5.5.1%20Events%20and%20Auto%20Timestamping).